# Getting the date of day X in week N

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

I have an object that looks like this:

```js
const availability = {
        week1: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
        week2: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
        week3: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
        week4: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
    };
```

This shows the availability of someone on the 1st, 2nd, ... week of the current month.

What I now need is the date of each day that is true. So for example the date of tuesday on the first week of this month, the date of tuesday for the second week of the month and so on.

I have checked out date-fns and moment.js but I can not figure out how I'd tackle this issue.

Comment: How do you determine the first week of the month? Do you start counting from the first Monday of the month? What if the first Monday is the 7th, the fourth Friday would be in the next month?, what about months that have 5 Mondays? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the requirement is that we start from **the first Monday** of the month then you could break the month into weeks and use your `availability` to map them. I am using the official [moment-range](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/) plugin here but you could calculate those ranges other ways:

```
const Moment = require('moment');
const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);

const availability = { week1: { mon: false, tue: true, wed: true, thu: true, fri: false, }, week2: { mon: false, tue: true, wed: true, thu: true, fri: false, }, week3: { mon: false, tue: true, wed: true, thu: true, fri: false, }, week4: { mon: false, tue: true, wed: true, thu: true, fri: false, }, };

const calcDays = (data, days) => {
  // get the assumed first Monday of the current month
  let fM = moment().startOf('month').isoWeekday('Monday')
  let cM = moment().month()

  // get the actual first Monday
  fM = fM.month() < cM ? fM.add(1, 'week').isoWeekday('Monday') : fM.month() > cM ? fM.subtract(1, 'week').isoWeekday('Monday') : fM

  // Calc the range based on first Monday and end of month
  const range = moment.range(fM, moment().endOf('month'));
  // Break into weeks
  const weeks = [...Array.from(range.by('week')), moment().endOf('month')]

  return Object.values(availability).reduce((r,c,i) => {
    var weekRanges = Array.from(moment.range(weeks[i], weeks[i + 1]).by('day'))
    Object.entries(c).map(([k, v], j) => v ? r.push(weekRanges[j].format()) : v)
    return r
  }, [])
}

console.log(calcDays(availability))
```

Outputs (**ran November 8th 2018**):

```
[ '2018-11-06T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-08T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-13T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-14T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-15T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-20T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-21T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-22T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-27T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-28T00:00:00+00:00',
  '2018-11-29T00:00:00+00:00' ]
```

You can see it [working here](https://repl.it/@akrion/WeekRanges)

Comment: What about november 1st?

Comment: Since the requirements are not clear the assumption is that we start from the first Monday of the month. As stated in the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function isAGoodDay (date) {
  var weekOfMonth = Math.floor(date.getDate() / 7) + 1;
  var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
  var day = days[dayOfWeek];
  if (day === '') return false;
  return availability['week'+weekOfMonth][day];
}

function listGoodDays(year, month) {
  var lastDay = new Date(new Date(year, month, 1)-1).getDate();
  return listOfdays[lastDay]
           .filter((d) => (isAGoodDay(new Date(year, month-1, d))))
           .map((d) => (new Date(year, month-1, d)));
}


const availability = {
        week1: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
        week2: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
        week3: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
        week4: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        },
        week5: {
            mon: false,
            tue: true,
            wed: true,
            thu: true,
            fri: false,
        }
    };


var days = ['','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri',''];
var listOfdays = 
  {"28" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
,"29" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
,"30" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
,"31" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
  };


console.log( listGoodDays(2018, 11) );
```